# Using variables in CGRectMake, Swift, UIkit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit

For an App I'm making i need to use variables to change the size and position of objects (Labels). I've tried `var example = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 100)`, hoping it would ignore the zeros (Not really thinking it  *would*  though). I then tried:

```
var example = 100
Label1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, example)
```

I changed the syntax a bit, adding "" and replacing the `CGRectMake` with `CGRect` etc, but nothing worked... I don't get what I'm doing wrong here... Help!

Comment: save the frame of the old label then set those values as the ones that remain unchanged in the new position 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGRectMake` takes `CGFloat`s for all of its arguments. Your sample code should work fine if you specify that `example` is supposed to be a `CGFloat`, using a type identifier:

```
         //  v~~~~ add this...
var example: CGFloat = 100
Label1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, example)
```

Otherwise, swift infers the type of `example` to be `Int`, and the call to `CGRectMake` fails, cuz it can't take an `Int` as a parameter...

Comment: This answer is outdated. See below.

Answer (score 66):

Below is the new syntax used since Swift 3.

```
CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, there is many ways to skin the cat. It all depends what your needs and requirements are (maybe you could elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve?). But one way to do it could be to set a variable when something happens, and then update the frame of the label. If you added a tap gesture recognizer to your view, and updated your label like so:

```
let myLabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestRecog = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestRecog)
}

func handleTap(sender:UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let newXposition = sender.locationInView(self.view).x
    let newYposition = sender.locationInView(self.view).y

    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(newXposition, newYposition, 200, 200)
}
```

This is just an example, and a very crude way of doing it. There are many other ways of doing it, but it hopefully gives you an idea of how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Swift allows syntax that Objective-C does not:

```
var example = 100
label.frame.size.height = example
```

In objective-C you would have to do it differently:

```
CGRect frame = label.frame;  //Create a temporary rect to hold the frame value
frame.size.height = example;
label.frame = frame;
```